# Removing formatting from formatted fields before calculation

Tags: jquery, formatting, field

I'm very inexperienced with jQuery, so please bear with me. I have some fields with numbers that format with commas, dollar signs, and percent signs as the user types. When a button is clicked, the below function fires. What I am trying to accomplish, is to have the fields unformat themselves so I can do some calculation and have the results pass to some other fields (I realize this is probably not the best way to do it). Otherwise, the other fields are just populated with "NaN".

The function works for removing the commas and percent signs, but for some reason won't remove the dollar signs in the two fields that have them.

Here are the two functions that format the fields with a jQuery plugin:

```
$('.dollar').keyup(function () {
  $(this).autoNumeric('init', {aSep: ',', aSign: '$', mRound: 'u', mDec: '0'})
});

$('.percentage').keyup(function () {
  $(this).autoNumeric('init', {aSep: ',', aSign: '%', pSign: 's', mRound: 'u', mDec: '0'})
});
```

Here is the function that unformats the fields, among other things:

```
$('#resultsBtn').on('click', function(){
            $('#output .sectionBox').fadeIn()
            ,$('#resultsBtn').hide()
            ,$('#fieldI').val('70')
            ,$('[id^=field]').each(function(){$(this).val($(this).val().replace(/,/g,''))})
            ,$('.dollar').each(function(){$(this).val($(this).val().replace(/$/g,''))})
            ,$('.percentage').each(function(){$(this).val($(this).val().replace(/%/g,''))})
        });`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your formatting of your function is wrong, you should try this:

```
$('#resultsBtn').on('click', function () {
    $('#output .sectionBox').fadeIn();
    $('#resultsBtn').hide();
    $('#fieldI').val('70');
    $('[id^=field]').each(function () {
        $(this).val($(this).val().replace(',', ''));
    })
    $('.dollar').each(function () {
        $(this).val($(this).val().replace('$', ''));
    });
    $('.percentage').each(function () {
        $(this).val($(this).val().replace('%', ''));
    });
});
```

Note the commas that I removed and the semicolons I added at the end of every function.
You don't really need the regex in the replace either.

A jsFiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/Bvfq8/2/

Comment: Man, I was hoping it would be something more glamorous! I've been going about it wrong this whole time. Thanks!